# ZendFrameWork mod_rewrite enabled but urls still nor working - wampserver 2.1?

Tags: zend-framework, wampserver

I have enabled enabled mod_rewrite and have the following in httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have set up an alias to point to the public folder in the project 127.0.0.1/whatford/

But i still have to prefix my url with index.php to access other controller/views example = 127.0.0.1/whatford/index.php/contact - instead of 127.0.0.1/whatford/contact ?

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: are you talking about a vhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this :
 `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = str_replace('index.php','',$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);`
added to the top of my index.php to get rid of the index.php in the url.

also check out this [Vhost in Zend Server](http://blog.srmklive.com/2010/12/27/how-to-create-virtual-hosts-using-zend-server-ce/), following along with this post you can make sure your apache setup is correct for ZF, even if you don't setup a full Vhost.

Comment: thanks for you answer i have used Dave Clark's method which is working now... many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try working with a vhost.

Here are settings you can try based on a domain name test.local

So if you're using Windows update C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts by adding the domain like this:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost 
    127.0.0.1       test.local
```

And if you're using Apache under Windows update the httpd-vhosts.conf file like this (Make sure you put in the correct folder name under DocumentRoot and Directory):

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
# NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\www\yourProjectApplicationFolder\public"
    ServerName test.local
    <Directory C:\www\yourProjectApplicationFolder\public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need to make sure you uncomment the

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

line in the Apache httpd.conf file so it looks like this:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then restart Apache and go to http://test.local and you should have your start page.

Let me know if that works for you or if you run into any more problems.

Cheers,

Dave